# Redirect std::cout to syslog on linux

Tags: c++, linux, syslog

My code contains a lot of `std::cout`.
I got a call from sysadmin telling me that I am filling up the `/var/log/messages` folder and the syslog filesystem. But, my user ID does not have access to either `/var`, which requires root permissions for writing, I don't use syslog.
My assumption is that somehow, Linux must be configured to redirect `cout` to the syslog server.

My question is what are the settings in Linux, which makes the above feasible (i.e. redirect `cout` to syslog)?

Comment: How do you invoke your program?

Comment: What makes you think that your heavy use of std::cout and the filling up of /var/log/messages is related?

Comment: If you want to redirect stdout to syslog, this question is not about C++ programming. Try adding better flags, maybe you'll get linux users attention ;)

Comment: @DevSolar The log messages shown by sysadmin are same what i would see on bash terminal via cout

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato I dont want to redirect to syslog. Infact, i am confused to why std::cout are being redirected to syslog. Hence, if i get to know what settings on linux enable this redirection, i can look them up.

Comment: @Jimm Sorry, just misinterpreted question. Are you calling this program from cron or something similar (not a terminal)?

Comment: no, i am calling the program from bash terminal like ./myprogram

Comment: The solution is in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638654/redirect-c-stdclog-to-syslog-on-unix

Comment: What is the name of this program?