# Do uClibc/glibc provide any feature to redirect errors to syslog?

Tags: c, linux, libc, uclibc

Do uClibc/glibc provide any feature to redirect errors to syslog?
The erros like "can't resolve symbol" need to go to syslog instead of stderr on console.

Comment: here the same question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665509/redirecting-standard-output-to-syslog

Comment: Why are such errors happening in the first place? Any message generated by libc indicates bugs in your program or build toolchain, and should not happen in a production environment...

Comment: I want to make sure that such errors are not happening in production environment. I am happy if syslog is empty after execution of production code :-). But I need to confirm it by looking into syslog. Note that it is notonly about coding. Some funny user could load an old version of library  in production environment. Without a logging system , this would be tough.

Comment: @LunarMushrooms: For glibc Fred has already provided the links. syslog calls are available on uClibc (atleast from looking @ the source) [syslog.h](http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/include/sys/syslog.h) & [syslog.c](http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/misc/syslog/syslog.c)

Comment: What is tricky here is, the errors produced inside glibc code (like can't resolve symbol) also need to be logged. Not only the application errors. I had a quick look at the sources of uclibc. I couldnt find any kind of redirection to syslog there (it implements syslog anyway). So I believe there is no such feature exists.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a daemon, the best option is using an init capable of this (e.g. InitNG). If this isn't possible, you can replace stderr early (not as nice, but if there's no other option...):

```
#!/bin/sh
init 2>&1 >/dev/console | tee /dev/console | logger
```

Something similar needs to be done for programs using pseudo-terminals. The easiest way is using a shell wrapper similar to the above snippet.